# FactoryBot Eventable ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, factory-bot

I have a factory that looks like:

```
factory :order_with_approval do
   status      'approved'
   association :approval, factory: :approval
end
```

Now, I need the approval model to take the order id and set it as the eventable id. I've been able to figure this out in the other direction by doing:

```
factory :cancellation do
  reason 'a reason'
  cancellation_date Date.current
  association :eventable, factory: :order
end
```

So what might work is if I can pass in something other than a new factory into the association. What I'd like to do is pass in the parent factory. Is that possible? Can I achieve this some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Cross-references might be resolved with `after` clause as [shown here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/wiki/Example-factories.rb-file):

```
factory :order_with_approval do
  status 'approved'
  association :approval, factory: :approval

  after(:build, :create) do |order, _evaluator|
    order.approval.update_attributes!(eventable: order)
  end
end
```

Comment: This would work to solve the problem listed above, but I'm running into an issue where this is being done in a call back upon creation. So, the creation blows up before it gets the approval created.

Comment: Then just assign the value instead of calling update_attributes.

Comment: It never gets to that step because the association blows up. I think there is a better way to structure the factories that I'm playing around with.

Comment: Create the `approval` association inside the `after` callback.